# How to install Nginx on Alpine using Docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, alpine-linux

I've set up Nginx on a `node:20-alpine` image and I get no errors, but the server isn't listening on the port specified.  When I enter `localhost:80` I get a `This site can't be reached` error.

I have:

```
FROM node:20-alpine AS react-build

ARG PORT=80

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install --omit=dev
RUN npm run build

FROM node:20-alpine AS react

WORKDIR /www

RUN apk update
RUN apk add nginx
RUN adduser -D -g 'www' www
RUN chown -R www:www /var/lib/nginx
RUN chown -R www:www /www

COPY --from=react-build /app/lib .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And:

```
user www;
worker_processes auto;
error_log error.log warn;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 2000;
  access_log access.log;

  server {
    listen 80;
    root /www;
    index index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    error_page 500 502 503 504;

    location / {
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

After which I run `docker builder build . -t react && docker run react`.

The result is that everything builds correct, it seems the server is listening and running, no errors, but when I try access it in browser it says the site can't be reached.

What am I doing wrong or what can I try to debug it further?

Comment: You have to map the port from the host to the contianer: `docker run -p "8080:80" react -d`

Comment: Thank you so much.  That is all I was missing, now it's working.  If you want to answer it I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map the port form the host to the container.

Just run `docker builder build . -t react && docker run -p "8080:80" react`; by doing so you bind the port `80` of your container to the port `8080` on your local machine.

If you want a docker compose file you can do something like this:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services: 
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
```

and then just run `docker-compose up --build -d`